# How to add required libraries to a pyqtdeploy project file for an Android app?

Tags: android, qt, pyqt, pyqtdeploy

I have already successfully deployed a QtWigets app to Android using PyQt5 and pyqtdeploy. However when I want to deploy a QML based app the app crashes.
What I found out is that Qt5QuickTemplates2.so and Qt5QuickControls2.so are missing for the following QML snippet:

```
import Quick 2.0
import QuickControls 2.5
...
```

How can I declare these libraries in the project file?
There are no ckeckable entries in Qt section.
There is just QtQuick and QtQml.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35342222) for the case when QML files and not `.so` libraries are missing from the generated Android APK package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily I found a solution.

It's not documented anywhere so I only know this workaround.
Before running androiddeployqt I had to copy a valid QML file into the build-directory where androiddeployqt can find this file.
Have a look into the android-lib*.so-deployment-settings.json file in the build-directory for the key "qml-root-path":
There a qml-root has been set. In my case it was build-android-32.

androiddeployqt is scanning this file and maybe also dependent qml files for import statements. And then it knows which additional libraries to deploy.

Answer (score -1):

You can try **deployqt** applications.

- If you are using **Linux**, try **linuxdeployqt** from [here](https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt)
- If you are using **Windows**, try **windeployqt** from [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html)

Alternative Solution:

- Just copy **all** of the **libraries and plugins** inside your **application path**
- Change the name of **Qt folder**
- Execute the **application**
- **Try to remove** all of the **libraries and plugins** (Not as root)
- The system will tell you that **files using by app** cannot be deleted.

Cheers!

Comment: I want to deploy an Android app. So deployqt is not an option and there is no folder where I could copy the files into. I am still talking about to deploy a apk.